# Busca de lojas por CEP

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

Estou desenvolvendo um site com PHP e MySQL onde cadastro diversas lojas, e cada loja atende a uma região da cidade.

Qual seria a melhor estratégia para adoptar neste caso, onde tenho o `CEP` do cliente e quero verificar qual é a loja mais próxima na cidade que poderá atender ao cliente?

Pensei em salvar a - `Lat` e `Long` da loja, e definir uma região a que ela atende com o Google Maps, mas como posso verificar depois se o `CEP` está dentro dessa área?

Answer (score 1):

Qual a granularidade das suas lojas? Cidade? Bairro? Quarteirão? Como o CEP é um código estruturado, você pode tentar fazer uma procura por partes sucessivamente maiores do CEP. Por exemplo, se o CEP do cliente é 89213-123, você poderia procurar por 8, 89, 892, 8921... a primeira procura poderia achar uma loja em Curitiba (88xxx-xxx), a segunda já vai isolar o Litoral Norte de SC, a terceira isola Joinville, e assim por diante.

Uma sofisticação desta procura pode ser a busca por proximidade do dígito não-coindicente, por exemplo uma loja no CEP 8922x-xxx provavemente atende melhor um cliente 8923x-xxx que uma loja 8927x-xxx, porque até onde percebo os Correios deixam CEPs geograficamente próximos com números 'próximos' também.

Certamente o Correio pode te vender um banco de dados com as coordenadas GPS dos CEPs, mas isso é cobrado e você precisa pagar pelas atualizações.